# How can I launch specific fragment at launch android app

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Fragment selectedFragment =  null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try
        {
            this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){}

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {


                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.homee:
                                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                                break;
                            case R.id.nav_search:
                                selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                                break;

                            case R.id.nav_notif:
                                selectedFragment = null;
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this ,SearchFragment.class));
                                break;
                        }

                        if (selectedFragment != null){
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
                        }

                    return true;
                }
        });

    }

}
```

This all is my code of main activity...what should I do so that when user comes in the app home fragment is opened by default as per this code when the user comes in the app he needs to press the home button to come into fragment...how can I by default like for example instagram as soon as a user comes in it keeps the user in home fragment how can I, I am using android material bottom navigation if you ask I can also provide xml file of this activity..ThankYou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your MainActivity onCreate method.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ExploreMainFragment());
        ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after you setup `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id. homee).setChecked(true)
```

Comment: At the end its showing error what should I do even after I put semicolon can you help...

Comment: Sir I made it work with another solution However thankyou :)